# Accessing existing windows postgresql database in WSL

Tags: database, postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pgadmin

I already have postgresql installed *(psql (PostgreSQL) 13.4)* and the local server set-up on my windows machine (along with pgAdmin4), and already have some databases in it.

I've recently installed WSL and planning on using it instead of windows+bash going forward. Hence I'm installing postgresql 13 for WSL. I follow https://pgdash.io/blog/postgres-13-getting-started.html for the installation:

```
# add the repository 
> sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list <<END 
> deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main 
> END

# get the signing key and import it 
> wget https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc sudo apt-key add
> ACCC4CF8.asc

# fetch the metadata from the new repo 
> sudo apt-get update

> sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-13
```

It installed postgres with `psql --version` = `psql (PostgreSQL) 13.4 (Ubuntu 13.4-1.pgdg20.04+1)`

Then I start the service with

```
> sudo service postgresql start
> sudo -u postgres psql
```

My questions are:

1. When I check the list of databases I have using `\l`, I can't see my existing postgres database that I have in my windows machine, why? and how do I connect/import it to the wsl?
2. How do I make the WSL database/server appears in my existing pgAdmin4 GUI? I have already a server for my windows machine (localhost, port 5432). How can I add database from the WSL server, since it has the same settings? For example, I tried creating new database via WSL psql command line `CREATE DATABASE ubuntu;`, and the new database appears in the WSL postgres list in terminal, but the pgAdmin GUI only shows database from my windows server. How do I sync both databases in windows and WSL and show them both in pgAdmin?

[database list in windows (from pgAdmin4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y59X.png)

[database list in WSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2062.png)

Thanks for the help

Comment: 1. Are you connecting to the instance you just installed or the previous/windows instance? I.e. which host or endpoint are you specifying with the `-h` arg in psql?

Comment: Hi, sorry can you elaborate more on that? I didn't remember to manually connecting to any instances, just installed the psql in ubuntu and then run them, so I guess it might be automatically connected to the wsl one I just installed. Is there a way to connect it to the windows one?

Comment: replying to @404